# Removing spaces from the fields in a pipe-delimited file using shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I am new to UNIX Shell scripting.

I need help in removing leading and trailing blank spaces from the fields. But I need to retain the spaces between the words.

Please have a look at the data sample and the desired result below to understand my problem.

Data Sample :

```
1-B48980007       |82984788|317      |ALQ|     |4423271    |              0|  |

I0000000000000000000245729|28887957|IL FR    |   |     |00000000573|              0|  |

I0000000000000000000245715|13822348|RPVIPPR  |   |     |00000000298|              0|  |

I0000000000000000000245721|15348717|AN BV    |   |     |00000001526|              0|  |
```

Desired Result:

```
1-B48980007|82984788|317|ALQ||4423271|0||

I0000000000000000000245729|28887957|IL FR|||00000000573|0||

I0000000000000000000245715|13822348|RPVIPPR|||00000000298|0||

I0000000000000000000245721|15348717|AN BV|||00000001526|0||
```

But I am getting the output as below on using the below command:

sed 's/ *\|/\|/g' file_name > testOP

pipeline('|') is a delimiter in my file. I need to remove the spaces before and after the pipeline but need to retain the spaces between the words for example: "IL FR" and "AN BV".

```
1-B48980007     |82984788|317|ALQ||4423271|           0||

I0000000000000000000245729|28887957|IL FR|  ||00000000573|            0||

I0000000000000000000245715|13822348|RPVIPPR|    ||00000000298|            0||

I0000000000000000000245721|15348717|AN BV|  ||00000001526|            0||
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Savitha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue with the below sed statement:

sed -e `'s/ *\|/\|/g'` -e `'s/press_tab_key_here*\|press_tab_key_here*/\|/g'` -e `'s/\| */\|/g'` file_name

to remove the tab spaces, I had to press "tab" key. '\t' didn't work in my case.

Thanks Michael, Potong and Triplee for all the help and support. :)

Answer (score 11):

Using:

```
sed -e 's/ *| */|/g' file_name
```

gives the desired result:

```
1-B48980007|82984788|317|ALQ||4423271|0||

I0000000000000000000245729|28887957|IL FR|||00000000573|0||

I0000000000000000000245715|13822348|RPVIPPR|||00000000298|0||

I0000000000000000000245721|15348717|AN BV|||00000001526|0||
```

Note that this approach removes only space characters. To exclude all whitespace, tab characters must be accounted for as well. With any POSIX-compliant implementation of sed, you could do this:

```
sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*/|/g' file_name
```

Or, with GNU extensions to the regex:

```
sed -e 's/\s*|\s*/|/g' file_name
```

Comment: Apparently his `sed` wants the pipe backslash-escaped, though.

Comment: I gave it as sed -e 's/ *\| */\|/g' filename. But still I have unwanted spaces in the output.

Comment: @Savitha Are there other forms of whitespace to remove, or just spaces as was stated in the question?

Comment: @Michael: I am sorry, if this is a silly question. But what are the other forms of whitespace?

Comment: @Savitha Not silly at all. Whitespace refers to characters that don't have a printed representation, instead being used for the spacing between other words. For working with lines in sed, relevant are spaces and tabs. Other forms of whitespace are relevant in more general situations, e.g., strings that can contain multiple lines have line breaking characters as whitespace.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for explaining... :) There are no whitespaces. I referred to only spaces as in the space seen after "1-B48980007 " before pipe and in " 0" before 0 in the line 1-B48980007 |82984788|317|ALQ||4423271| 0||. Please refer to this line in my original post. The spaces are not shown properly in this.

Comment: @Michael: I tried both GNU extensions to the regex and POSIX...but I don't know what am I missing, I still have spaces in my output.

Comment: @Michael: It seems to be tabs, which is not getting removed and not spaces. I am sorry for not identifying it as whitespace :( I need to remove both "spaces" and "tabs" now.

Comment: @Michael GNU extensions to the regex worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
sed 's/\s*|\s*/|/g' input_file
```

EDIT: removed unnecessary parens and alternation

Comment: I tried your solution, but still there are spaces in my output.

Comment: Are they spaces or perhaps blank lines? If the latter prepend the above command with `/^$/d;`

Comment: I believe, its the "tab(Chr(9))", which is not getting removed.

Answer (score -1):

considering comma as separator in csv or text files for data columns here is one to remove leading trailing, makes space single.

```
cat filename.txt | fmt -su | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed 's/ *$//g' | sed 's/ ,/,/g' | sed 's/, /,/g'
```